# What is the proper test to determine if a result is above the normal set of values?

Tags: time-series, trend, excel, quality-control

I'm a chemist who has been asked to put my statistics hat on, and I'm looking for some help.

Situation: Every month we get a report with the number of guest complaints for each item we sell.  Each month, I want to be able to identify which items have an increase in monthly guest complaints that falls above the "normal" monthly rate.  (I'm using the term normal to describe the monthly complaint value for a product without a quality issue.)  I'm trying to give my team a simple tool that will help guide their efforts towards products that may have a quality issue, and should be further investigated.

Ideally, I would like a test that I can run via Excel.

Comment: How do you ascertain the "normal" monthly rate?

Comment: This sounds like a standard SPC/Shewhart chart problem.  I would start looking there.

Comment: @User1865345 "Normal" was probably a poor choce of words, since it likely has a very specific meaning in the statistics world.  When I used the word normal I was trying to describe the monthly complaint value over the last 11 months for a product that does not have a quality issue.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please add that info in your question body @Kat.

Comment: Done.  Thanks for the suggestions.  New to this platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try estimating the average number of complaints and its standard deviation.  Then for a new monthly report, calculate Z=(#complaints - avg)/sd. If Z is less than -2 or greater than 2, it's an outlier with less than a 5% chance of being observed given the data.  It's called a Z-test, which is based on Z-scores.  You number of complaints may not be normally distributed, so you could transform #complaints into ranks, of ven der Waerden scores first before calculating the average and standard deviation.